# How to change screen after call is rejected or disconnected in android

Tags: android, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener

I am making a demo on call Dialer application, I have successfully done incoming and outgoing functionalities. Now my problem is i want to change the activity when call is rejected or disconnected. I have tried lot of things and also digging thru many of links. Can anyone please help me just how to switch the screen when call is disconnected. My reciver for call_state is as below:

```
package com.example.dialingdemo;

import Utils.Const;
import Utils.Pref;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.CallLog;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {

            final String savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString(
                    "android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent i = new Intent(context, CallScreen.class);
                    i.putExtra("incomingNumber", savedNumber);
                    i.putExtras(intent);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                    context.startActivity(i);

                    Toast.makeText(context, "OUTGOING CAL to : " + savedNumber,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, 1000);
        }

        else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

            final String incomingNumber = intent
                    .getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Call from:" + incomingNumber,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    Intent i = new Intent(context, IncomingCall.class);
                    i.putExtra("incomingNumber", incomingNumber);
                    i.putExtras(intent);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                    context.startActivity(i);

                }
            }, 1000);

        } else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)
                || intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                        TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {

            // This code will execute when the call is disconnected
            if (Const.call_state.equals("1")) {

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        Intent i = new Intent(context, CallScreen.class);

                        i.putExtras(intent);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                        context.startActivity(i);

                    }
                }, 1000);
            } else if (Const.call_state.equals("2")) {

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        Intent i = new Intent(context, CallScreen.class);

                        i.putExtras(intent);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                        context.startActivity(i);

                    }
                }, 1000);

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: so, what problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

Use `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE` to detect call is ringing,off hook or droped

```
String callState= receiverIntent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

if (callState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
             //call is disconnected or rejected
}
```